# why doesn't my jquery work (using delay, hasclass, addclass, removeclass, keyUp, keyDown functions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So what the code is supposed to do is when a user clicks on the input field, and presses a key, after keyup then after 2 seconds the field is supposed to turn red. On key down it's supposed to turn yellow. Then on keyup again, after 2 seconds it's supposed to turn red.

Not sure why this isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <style>
  p { margin: 8px; font-size:16px; }
  .red { background:red;}
  .yellow { background:yellow;}
  .white {background: white;}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input id="target" type="text" />
</form>
<br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#target").keyUp(function(){//STARTFUNCTION keyUp
if (  $('#target').hasClass("yellow")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("yellow");
  }//end if
  if (  $('#target').hasClass("white")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("white");
  }//end if

//after 2 seconds, add the class red
$("#target").delay(2000).queue(function(next){//start function
    $(this).addClass("red");
    //next();
}); //end function
}).keydown(function(event) {//start function
   if ( $('#target').hasClass("red")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("red");
  }//end if
   if (  $('#target').hasClass("white")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("white");
  }//end if
    $(this).addClass("yellow");
});//end function


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set this up in a fiddle.

Comment: @Dave, at least check your statements.. `keyup` and `keydown` exist in core jQuery (although Pavan's `keyUp` was not spelled correctly, lowerCase u). http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: Also comments aren't supposed to be just noise.. You don't need a comment to figure out if it's a function or an if start..

Comment: Okay, I could have been nicer.  But if you're posting code that generates javascript errors and your question isn't "why is this causing an error" then you should probably spend more time working on the question before posting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your file corrected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <style>
  p { margin: 8px; font-size:16px; }
  .red { background:red;}
  .yellow { background:yellow;}
  .white {background: white;}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input id="target" type="text" />
</form>
<br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#target").keyup(function(){//STARTFUNCTION keyUp
if (  $('#target').hasClass("yellow")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("yellow");
  }//end if
  if (  $('#target').hasClass("white")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("white");
  }//end if

//after 2 seconds, add the class red
$("#target").delay(2000).queue(function(next){//start function
    $(this).addClass("red");
    //next();
}); //end function
}).keydown(function(event) {//start function
   if ( $('#target').hasClass("red")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("red");
  }//end if
   if (  $('#target').hasClass("white")){//start if
  $('#target').removeClass("white");
  }//end if
    $(this).addClass("yellow");
});//end function


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive `$("#target").keyUp` should be `$("#target").keyup`.  You also have an extra `});` at the end of your script.

Comment: thanks Rocket - I saw it as keyup somewhere else and just went with it - i'll stick with the api documentation now on.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but the most obvious error is that at the end of your Javascript block you have:

```
});//end function

});
```

Where instead it should be:

```
});//end function
```

Comment: thanks dude my editor doesn't do a good job of showing me corresponding curly brackets

Comment: You don't need it, use proper indenting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#target').keyup(function () {
    setTimeout('$("#target").attr("class","red");', 2000);
});

$('#target').keydown(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Do not pass strings to `setTimeout`!  It uses `eval`.  Pass functions.